# PHP OCI8 for Oracle DB does not work with IIS (OCI_CRED_EXT) on Windows

Tags: php, laravel, oracle, yajra-datatable

Running PHP IIS server.

***error Use of undefined constant OCI_CRED_EXT - assumed 'OCI_CRED_EXT' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)***

By running php artiasan serve the connection to the Oracle database is working.

**configuration:**

Windows 10 x64 Pro versioan 20H2

Manually installed 7.3  Non Thread Safe x86 add path to env

IIS Server version 10

Laravel 8

OCI 8.2.2 for WIndows Non Thread Safe (NTS) x86 unpack C:\Program Files
(x86)\Php(X86)\7.3

composer install laravel-oci8

instantclient-basic-nt-11.2.0.4.0 add path to env

add php.ini extensions:php_oci8.dll

**command cmd**

***php --ri oci8***

oci8

OCI8 Support => enabled

OCI8 DTrace Support => disabled

OCI8 Version => 2.2.0

Oracle Run-time Client Library Version => 11.2.0.4.0

Oracle Compile-time Instant Client Version => 10.2

Directive => Local Value => Master Value

oci8.max_persistent => -1 => -1

oci8.persistent_timeout => -1 => -1

oci8.ping_interval => 60 => 60

oci8.privileged_connect => Off => Off

oci8.statement_cache_size => 20 => 20

oci8.default_prefetch => 100 => 100

oci8.old_oci_close_semantics => Off => Off

oci8.events => Off => Off

Statistics =>

Active Persistent Connections => 0

### Active Connections => 0

***phpinfo*** does not display oci8 module.

***error_log*** PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_oci8.dll' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Php(X86)\7.3\ext\php_oci8.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Php(X86)\7.3\ext\php_php_oci8.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

***php_oci8.dll*** the library ***exists*** in the specified path.

tried to check the instant client oracle, sqlplus connects to the database.

read a lot of information, but I'm stumped how to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

You configuration isn't picking up Instant Client.  Where is it installed and have you set PATH?  Maybe you need to move libraries to where the php dlls are?

Some really old notes I have are at https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/how-to-use-iis,-php-and-oracle

Also, for historic reasons OCI_CRED_EXT isn't supported on Windows, see https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-8.0.3/ext/oci8/oci8.c#L941-L948

What do you need OCI_CRED_EXT for?

(And why are you using such old Oracle Client libraries! - you should be able to drop in a newer set, since they keep compatibility)

Comment: path added to environment variables for instant client. Added libraries to php, no result.
11 client I use to connect to oracle 9i database.OCI_CRED_EXT how can I disable this authorization.
Why does artisan serve work fine with connect oracle9i database?